# "Went and got" — is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, conjunctions

Trying to find out if phrases like "went and got" are correct, e.g.:

> She **went and got** the book.

Comment: I think it's probably unintentional that your *particular* example allows for the possibility that *went* really does have the literal sense of *physically going somewhere*. Assuming I'm right, perhaps you could consider editing to a different example where that interpretation *can't* apply, such as [He went and hit me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+and+hit+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. "Went and got" match and can therefore be used together.  As a simple test, you can try "she went," and also "she got," so putting them together is fine.  If you said: "She went to the store and got the book," you probably wouldn't even question the phrase.  Dropping "to the store" is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think in *American* English, OP's example probably comes across as slightly odd, bordering on tautologous. But certainly lots of Brits have no problem with, for example, [He went and left me](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NZmLVEgiyysC&pg=PA35&dq=%22went%20and%20left%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=USvoUpTfBqef0QWEhYDoBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22went%20and%20left%22&f=false), particularly in an informal spoken context.

That's because in *British* English, we often use *to **go and** [do it]* meaning *to **proceed** [to do it]* (often, in contexts where *doing it* was unexpected, amusing, and/or offensive to the speaker). But I don't think the usage in common in AmE.

My advice to OP would be to avoid the doubled verb form unless it's important to convey the sense of both leaving *and* returning/fetching. That same advice is in the example from *The Dimwit's Dictionary* which I linked to above, where [Robert Hartwell Fiske](http://www.vocabula.com/RobertHartwellFiske.asp) (endorsed by [William Safire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Safire)) says "DELETE ***went and***".

Comment: In American English it is the same. "I went and did something". It is a bit informal and so not appropriate for more formal written work. But how is 'to go' (went) and 'to get' (got) odd or tautologous?

Comment: Good answer.  "She went and got the book" is grammatically fine, but it is redundant and therefore something to avoid for stylistic reasons.  Unless you're giving more information about *where* she went, simply saying that someone had to fetch something implies that they moved, so no need to spell it out.

Comment: @Mitch: We don't know the context, but to my British ear, OP's example could easily suggest something along the lines of *"She liked the film so much she went and got the book"*. Where *went and* might well imply nothing whatsoever about *physical* movement (she might have just downloaded it onto her Kindle while she was still in the cinema, for all I know). I didn't find any earlier questions on *go and do it = (unexpectedly, suddenly) proceed to do it*, and I feel a bit diffident about telling *you* what Americans say, but I'm not convinced it's much used in AmE.

Comment: It might be added that the _went and_ construction has a secondary nuance, indicating affront or indignation at the action undertaken (especially in the historical present tense and in conjunction with _on me_, indicating the action has had a negative impact on the speaker): “And then, without as much as a word of farewell, he goes and disappears on me!” — “And then of course he went and got himself killed, so now we'll never know where he hid the treasure.”

Comment: "I'm not much convinced it's much used in AmE" ...really? Not that it should help with convincing but ngrams on "went and got" has a higher frequency in AmE than BrE.

Comment: @Janus: You're quite right. I knew *unexpectedly* didn't quite capture it when I wrote the text, and adding *suddenly* in the comment didn't improve it much. When I later added a comment to the Q, I didn't know why I was so pleased to have hit upon *He goes and hits me*. I should have realised then, it's often used with that *indignation* overtone. Will edit into answer, ty.

Comment: @Mitch: Bear in mind I don't *know* I'm right - it's just a sense. But I'd expect well over 99% of all instances of *went and got* wouldn't be for the sense I'm talking about, so that wouldn't tell me anything. I just checked *every* instance of *goes and drops* where I could actually see the context. All four that were relevant (eight were literal and/or "accidental collocations") were from *British* authors. I'm not resting my case, but that *does* seem to support it somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit crude when you could have used 'went to get' but it's equally valid English.

They do have different connotations; "went and got" implies the description of an action in more of a narrative context, following the action step by step (and possibly in the first person); "went to get" is more clearly past tense and - at least to me - infers a summarisation of a potentially complex set of actions.

It's all open to interpretation though!

Comment: I would say that "went to get" is semantically different from "went and got".  The first version leaves open the possibility that the person has not yet returned from the errand; the latter implies that both the going and the getting have been completed.  However, I suspect that's why "went and got" is a common form in casual English -- it's the natural past-tense version of "went to get".

Comment: @Amelia, _went to get_ does not necessarily imply that the getting is completed. “Where's Martin?” — “Oh, he went to get some milk from the store, he'll be back in a bit.”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  That's what I was trying to say; I guess I wasn't clear.  It's "went and got" that implies that both are completed.  So the two are different in meaning, not just in grammar.

Comment: @Amelia, so you did! I must have switched the two around when I read your comment—apologies!